# Terminator: disable middle click closing the tabs

Tags: command-line, gnome, 22.04, mouse, terminator

I want to stop Terminator (Ubuntu-22.04) to close the current tab if i middle click on the tab title. I often close the tabs accidentally when there is a process running in the current tab.

I am using `x11` as display manager.

I do not want to disable the middle button entirely because i use this to paste.

I already set the `org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences action-middle-click-titlebar` to `'none'`:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences action-middle-click-titlebar none
```

But that did not work.

Is there any option?

Answer (score 0):

Encountered the same problem

maybe Other ways to circumvent

close confirm
https://github.com/gnome-terminator/terminator/pull/834
https://github.com/gnome-terminator/terminator/issues/165

OR,
maybe need a terminator plugin to prevent it.